# Where to place permission declarations

Tags: android

Just making sure.

If I have an app that has a separate back-end library service app; I need to place my permission declarations in the manifest file of the main application even though the library portion of the application is actually performing the functions declared in the permission declarations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, nothing in your library's manifest is used when building the application. Even the package name is ignored. (This actually causes problems if you define custom attributes in XML and need to use an application namespace to reference the attributes in other XML. You have to copy the XML files into the application project and change the xmlns declaration to match the application's package name.)

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. Just like if you were to use an Activity from a back-end library, the Activity must be declared in the main applications Manifest.